# Is this anomalous phenomenon about the gravitational blueshift effect experimentally tenable?

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle, gravitational-redshift

According to relativity [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vspVt.png)], if there is a light source $B$ with a frequency $\nu_B$ at a distance $d$ from an observer $A$ inside a uniform gravitational field of $g$, the frequency of the light emitted from the source is blue-shifted to $\nu_A$ as measured by observer $A$ complying with the equation below: [See Figure-(a).]

$$\nu_A=\sqrt{\frac{c+gd/c}{c-gd/c}}\nu_B$$

However, according to Einstein's equivalence principle (EEP), if two spacecraft, separated by a distance $d$, and away from any gravitational field, accelerate in a way that observer $A$ located inside one of these spacecraft measures that:

**1-** The other accelerating craft is always at rest WRT him, and

**2-** The acceleration in his ($A$'s) vicinity is $g$ uniformly,

he can apply the above equation for the light emitted from the engine of the craft ahead [See Figure-(b).], which means that there can be a considerable blueshift for the source $B$ in the place of $A$. Now, if $d$ is long enough, whether or not $\nu_B$ and $g$ are great, $\nu_A$ can change into a gamma-ray frequency that can easily kill observer $A$ due to, say, cancer. (choose $d$ a number very close to $c^2/g$.)

This is not a paradox, but rather a weird phenomenon to me because it implicitly asserts that if you slightly accelerate your car towards a visible star in the horizon at night, you will receive the star's light as gamma rays that can kill you if the star is distant enough and the star or its shining satellite undergoes the same acceleration (in magnitude and direction) as your car incidentally. Because your car and the star/satellite abruptly fall into the same accelerated frame of reference, and you are allowed to use the above formula.

Has this phenomenon been detected experimentally or there is something wrong with my deduction?

[image: Blueshift Anomaly]

---

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vspVt.png)]  R. Resnick, **Introduction to Special Relativity**, p. 212 (John Wiley and Sons, New York, 1968).

Comment: I think the issue could be that the derivation for the formula presupposes the two objects were in the same accelerating frame for all time. If you were accelerating in the same direction as the distant star for the entire duration that the light ray was heading to you (it would take years), then by the time the ray gets to you, you will have ludicrous speed (and ludicrous blueshift) relative to Earth. Otherwise, if you're accelerating in the same direction as the star only momentarily, then maybe the derivation doesn't apply? I apologize if my guess is wrong.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal Good try!  However, I think that as you accelerate, you must quickly detect the blueshift for the photons which were being emitted long ago, and now are all before your eyes at the instant you accelerate. I am also not sure about this guess!

Answer (score 1):

> if you slightly accelerate your car towards a visible star in the horizon at night, you will receive the star's light as gamma rays that can kill you if the star is distant enough and the star or its shining satellite undergoes the same acceleration (in magnitude and direction) as your car incidentally.

That is not quite how it works. Don’t forget that the EEP describes the equivalence between a uniform gravitational field and a constant acceleration reference frame. So that means that the situation must be analyzed in a reference frame which has been accelerating steadily forever. That does not exclude your scenario, but requires some care in the analysis.

Specifically, let’s assume for simplicity that the star and the car have been inertial for a long time prior to the small acceleration. And suppose further that the acceleration occurs exactly at the moment that both the car and the star are momentarily at rest in the non inertial frame. So, indeed as you suggested the light received in that moment will be strongly blueshifted due to the EEP “gravitational” field. Thus far your analysis is correct.

However, the mistake is in ignoring the emission. Because of the great distance the emission occurred a long time ago. And because the acceleration occurred when the star was at rest in the accelerated frame that means that previously the star’s initial velocity was “up” away from the car. And because it was so long ago the star must have been traveling very fast away at the time of emission. And therefore the light from the star would be substantially redshifted on emission, simply due to the Doppler effect.

The combination of the Doppler red shift at emission and the gravitational blue shift at reception leads to the observed wavelength. If it is non-lethal in one frame then it will be non-lethal in all frames.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following. What do you mean by "non inertial frame". On the other hand, if the mentioned combination is lethal, the anomaly is not resolved to me yet. Do you mean that it is *possible* that you accelerate your car towards a star, and die of cancer?

Comment: @Mohammad Javanshiry The non inertial frame is the accelerated reference frame. More precisely it is a Rindler frame on flat spacetime. 

Why would the combination be lethal? It is non-lethal in the inertial frame and if it is non-lethal in one frame it is non-lethal in all frames.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency shift doesn't care about acceleration, but relative velocity. This is a bit tricky in curved spacetimes, so we'll just consider your example of accelerating spaceships.

In that case, $\Delta t = d/c$ is just the travel time of the light and the term $gd/c = g\cdot\Delta t = \Delta v$ nothing but the relative velocity picked up by the observing spaceship compared to the velocity at time of emission (assuming the ship has a velocity that's small compared to the speed of light, ie it only covered a negligible distance).

That's where your example with the car and star goes wrong, as the car did not accelerate for the duration of the light travel and hence hasn't picked up the necessary velocity to shift the star's light into the gamma spectrum.

Comment: Then, what about the observer in the gravitational field in case (a)? Any velocity is meaningless to him, however, he can use the equation. I think that involving velocity is admissible by the observer relative to whom the crafts are in motion, but not by observer $A$.

Comment: There's no unique notion of relative velocity at a distance in curved spacetime. What you can do is things like use a family of observers, or do a space/time decomposition and look at change in proper diststance within a spatial slice, or parallel transport velocity vectors along a curve.

Comment: For example, if you have two observers sitting at fixed Scharzschild coordinates within the gravitational field generated by a spherically symmetric mass, they will have zero velocity according to the second notion if you use the spatial slices induced by those coordinates. However, if they exchange light signals, parallel transport along the light trajectory will yield a non-zero relative velocity, which is the origin of the frequency shift.