# What is the frequency of a freely falling light-source measured by observer standing on planet?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-redshift

Assume that a light source is falling freely on a planet with a nearly uniform gravitational field. If the light source, reaching a velocity $v$, emits a photon towards an observer standing on the planet exactly beneath the source, what would be the photon's frequency received by this observer?

My guess is:

$$\nu'=\sqrt{\frac{c+gd/c}{c-gd/c}}×\sqrt{\frac{c+v}{c-v}}\nu$$

where $\nu'$ is the frequency measured by the observer on the planet, $\nu$ is the frequency of the photon in the light source's rest frame, and $d$ is the distance of the light source from the planet at the emission time as measured by the observer. The instantaneous velocity $v$ is also measured by the observer.

In my formula, I tried to consider the effects of both the gravitational blueshift and the blueshift due to the Doppler effect. Have I combined these effects in the right form?!

Comment: It is the regular special relativistic doppler times the gravitational blueshift

Comment: @Yukterez Do you then think that my equation is correct?

Comment: No, the gravitational redshift is √((1-rs/r1)/(1-rs/r2)) where rs is the Schwarzschild radius und r1, r2 are the radii at which the transmitter and the receiver are.

Comment: @Yukterez I mentioned that *g* is uniform.

Comment: @Yukterez I do not think so: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533994/is-this-anomalous-phenomenon-about-the-gravitational-blueshift-effect-experiment

Comment: In that link you reference p. 212 of Resnik's introduction to SR. There the gd/c term is eqivalent to v, in the original there is an = where you have a ×, see https://i.imgur.com/Y6I8IEn.png . My resolution that in a uniform field there is only the relative velocity SR Doppler, but no gravitational redshift still stands